# Create Pages for database content

Tags: database

i added a custom table to the wordpress database with a list of names and a description.
I wrote a custom function to display all the names in a table.
Now i want to have an extra page for every name where you can see the persons description after clicking on the persons name.
Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a custom table. Read the top answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/6472/39309) which recommends using Custom Post Types.

As for displaying the data, I'd recommend you investigate [Custom Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates). Then you can create a page that loads your data however you'd like.